# ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed (Windows 7, python 2.7, already installed pillow with pip)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, inkscape

Specs: 
 - 32 bit python 2.7.12
 - Anaconda 4.1.1 (32 bit)
 - pillow 3.3.0
 - Windows 7

I keep getting the error

```
ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed
```

when trying to run a plugin in inkscape, so I looked up this tutorial (http://effbot.org/zone/pil-imaging-not-installed.htm) and went through the steps.

The second step was to type "python -v" into the terminal and then trying to import Image. Whenever I tried to import it, I would get the error

```
ImportError: No module named image
```

I checked sys.path, and C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages (which is where the PIL folder is) is there.

What else can I do to eventually allow my inkscape plugin to work?